# Custom Object Tab not visible in Communities

Tags: community, custom-object

Does any one know why do Custom Objects do not appear in Communities? I have set up tabs and created Sharing settings for the object. And also in the Community User Profile, the tab is not hidden

Answer (score 1):

If you've gone into `Setup > Create > Apps > Community` and have added the tab there, the problem you're seeing would most likely occur because you didn't check the box where it says `"Overwrite Users' Personal Custom App Customizations"`.

If you didn't check that box, any customizations a user has made prior to the change (including you) wouldn't reflect the changes you made when adding the new tab.

Comment: I did check that. The solution was to clone the Community User Profile (Default) and in the cloned profile tick the Custom Object Access specifiers. For some reason we cannot edit the default Profile's Access specifiers

Comment: As with the Standard User, Marketing User, etc, the default Community User Profile cannot be edited. It must be cloned and then edited.

Answer (score 0):

When the Deployment status of the custom object is checked as "In Development" other users won't be able to view or use the object in community.Change the Deployment status as "Deployed" to make it viewable by all users.

Answer (score -1):

Your first step should be to go to https://www.google.com/search?q=salesforce+set+up+communities and to see what you find.

When submitting a question like this, which is asking for ways to do something that should be able to be done easily, citing what you have already tried and showing that you have made an effort to find, read, and follow specific documentation will help you get your question answered better.

Comment: Hi, I have been through the whole document. Anyway, I got working. The solution was to clone the Community User Profile (Default) and in the cloned profile tick the Custom Object Access specifiers. For some reason we cannot edit the default Profile's Access specifiers